# Does Google Cloup Platform have a Github like repository

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

I am very new to both GCP and github.

For an application running on GCP, I want to push my code from my local machine to GCP. I know that GCP is very well connected with Github.

However I am wondering if GCP has a service similar to github for hosting private repositories? If so, where can I find more info about it.

If not, is there a way to avoid a separate paid monthly subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here is the documentation : https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/